# System fails to suspend, "ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked"

Tags: suspend

Whenever I attach my USB phone, I can no longer suspend my machine. Even detaching my phone does not work.

```
ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
ACPI: EC: event blocked
ACPI: EC: EC stopped
PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
IRQ 29: no longer affine to CPU2
smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
IRQ 18: no longer affine to CPU3
IRQ 23: no longer affine to CPU3
IRQ 26: no longer affine to CPU3
IRQ 31: no longer affine to CPU3
smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
ACPI: Low-level resume complete
ACPI: EC: EC started
PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
x86: Booting SMP configuration:
smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x1
 cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
CPU1 is up
smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x2
 cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
CPU2 is up
smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
 cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
CPU3 is up
ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
sdhci-pci 0000:02:00.0: MMC controller base frequency changed to 50Mhz.
ACPI: EC: event unblocked
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
```

I am using `systemctl suspend -i` with

> 4.18.0-15-generic #16-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/wakeupDevice  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
LID       S4    *disabled  platform:PNP0C0D:00
SLPB      S3    *disabled  platform:PNP0C0E:00
IGBE      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:19.0
EXP3      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.2
XHCI      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.0
EHC1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
HDEF      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
```

Comment: I've been looking at this problem on and off for a couple of years. Yesterday was the most recent: [Battery drain when sleeping. Suspend too fast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135240/battery-drain-when-sleeping-suspend-too-fast?noredirect=1#comment1882318_1135240)

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problem is hardware dependent (ACPI tables). When a Linux system boots up, you can find these lines in the `dmesg` output:

```
[    0.x] ACPI : EC: interrupt unblocked
[    0.x] ACPI : EC: event unblocked
```

I believe the second one is not present in your log (not sure this is the only problem here). Maybe try to update the USB driver or firmware of your machine.

If the issue persists with a live OS (from USB) it's probably an issue regarding your firmware (SMI / ACPI implementation).

If you can't solve this by updating, it may be worth checking the DSDT or SSDT tables (containing AML code for ACPI procedures) related to "suspend" or S3 resume.

Check the ACPI doc for more details on those procedures: https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/ACPI_6_2.pdf#G8.1371219